# Using php cookie to detect if vistor has submitted email, if so take him straight to sales page

Tags: php

When people visit my site, I want those who have already visited my site and submitted their email to bypass my email submit page and go straight to my sales page.

I have an index.php which is the following:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
  header("location: salespage.php");
exit;
}
else
{
  header("location: emailsubmit.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<h1>My first PHP page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So if there is no cookie, they are new and have not submitted their email, so they redirect to 'emailsubmit.php'
They then enter their email address and click submit to be taken to the welcome page, 'welcome.php'

welcome.php is the following:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", "true", $expire);
?>

<html>
<body>
<h1>welcome, email submitted.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So this welcome page sets a cookie that lasts 30 days.

Now when they revisit my site, instead of seeing the email submit form again, the index.php redirects them straight to salespage.php.

Have I got everything right there?

It seems to be working, but I wanted to ask an expert if it is absolutely correct.

Do I need to put another 'exit;' after the second header("location term?

Also, can I remove the  stuff and just have the index.php file simply as a php code:-

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
  header("location: salespage.php");
exit;
}
else
{
  header("location: emailsubmit.php");
}
?>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have exit in if condition ? You are any ways redirecting so i guess that is not required

Also what if customer comes after one month why will you ask for email again. 
What if he clears his cookies? He will be prompted for the email again.

I would suggest you to store  his email and check from database itself instead of cookies,  if the email exist and then redirect him accordingly.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: So there is no need for the exit in the if condition?

Comment: No your program already redirects the user to new page also use database instead of cookies to determine if the user is already registered.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip.  I'll remove it.  Also, I'll need to do some research about using database.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What research? Can I help?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a complete newbie at coding.  So let me know the kinds of things I should research about.  It would take too much of your time to explain everything I need, so just give a few things for me to research about, and I'll probably post an example when I understand things a bit better.

Comment: Refer any website teaching mysql insert and select queries. Please open separate tickets for this.